# Add more variables to if statement

Tags: javascript

I am not a programmer and I know nothing about java script.
I am sure that you are already hate me, but I've honestly searched for the answer whole day and I am getting crazy.

I am trying to edit, a part of code on my wordpress website.
Here's the code:

```
if(name != 'name1') return true;
```

How can I add more variables? I've tried adding || and &&:

```
if(name != 'name1' || 'name2') return true;
```

else if:

```
if(name != 'name1') {
return true;
}
else if(name != 'name2') {
return true;
}
```

and many more combinations that I was able to find online.

I am sure that it's a simple fix, but I can't spend months of learning javascript to edit a straightforward function on my website.

I would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to check with another variable.

In this case, you need to use a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) operator, because if you use [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()), the condition is always `true.`

```
if (name !== 'name1' && name !== 'name2') return true;
```

Some words to the use of `name` as variable.

This is not advisable, because [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a reserved property of window.

All global variables could be accessed by taking the window object and the name as property.

Comment: Thank you very much, the && helped. My syntax was incorrect earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what you're looking for but maybe you're just mixing up the terms. Variable is your `name` and the thing to which the variable is compared to is a so called string - here `'name1'` or `'name2'`.

Try it like this:

```
if(name !== 'name1' || name !== 'name2') return true;
```

use || for OR (only one condition needs to be true)
use && for AND (both conditions need to be true)

Comment: Thank you very much, the && helped. My syntax was incorrect earlier.

Answer (score 1):

As others already suggested you can chain several statements with the logical AND (&&) operator. Once a statement is false it will return false without checking the other statements. With that in mind, you can `return` the whole statement if you are only interested if it is `true` or `false`

```
return (name != 'name1' && name != 'name2');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what your expected result is, if you want to verify if it's not 'name1' and 'name2' at the same time this should do it

```js
if(name != 'name1' || name != 'name2') return true;
```

this uses the `||` (or) operator and returns `true` if `name` is either not name1 or either not name2, for example if the variable `name` is equal to "name1" it will return true.
 Another option is

```js
if(name != 'name1' && name != 'name2') return true;
```

This will return true if `name` is neither "name1" and "name2" so the variable `name` must be different from "name1" and "name2" at the same time, you can read more about this [here](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-and-and-or-operators-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you very much, the && helped. My syntax was incorrect earlier.

Comment: All answers that I've received are correct. Unfortunately I can only chose one, so I decided to give it to a person who was downvoted for no reason.

I apreciatte your help.